# update variable string value in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I need to update the value of a variable in a bash script and write the changes to the file. My attempts have either replace the key without strings or deleted the value.

Here's what ive tried :

```
   sed -ri 's|^(VARIABLE_KEY\s*=\s*).*|\new_java-microservice.jar|' path_to_file/bashscript.sh
    
   sed -i  "s#\(.*VARIABLE_KEY =\)\( .*\)#\1 "new_java-microservice.jar"#" path_to_file/bashscript.sh

   sed -i 's/VARIABLE_KEY =.*/VARIABLE_KEY ="new_java-microservice.jar"/' path_to_file/bashscript.sh
```

script

```
#!/bin/bash

COMMAND="$1"
HOME="/root/service/"
BASE="${HOME}/javaservice"
VARIABLE_KEY="existing-java.jar"

case "${COMMAND}" in
    "start")
        nohup java -jar ${BASE}/${VARIABLE_KEY} start > /dev/null 2>&1 &
    ;;
    
    "stop")
        #....
    ;;
    
    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop}"
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: The problem was the space before the `=` ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -i 's/^VARIABLE_KEY=.*/VARIABLE_KEY="new_java-microservice.jar"/' path_to_file/bashscript.sh
```